# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I am planning to install Ubuntu along with Win7 on my system.
I have 2 different drives C: and E:.
E: drive is created after shrinking the Windows C: partition.
Can I use my E drive for installing Ubuntu?
Also is there any guide to step by step installation of ubuntu along with windows.

Answer (score 1):

Good that you trying out Ubuntu,

Delete E: and make a unpartitioned space through windows 7 disk management.

When you start Ubuntu installation select the free space.

Please mention the version also

Link
[Dual Desktop windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/step-by-step-guide-installing-ubuntu-11-04-natty-on-a-windows-7-dual-booting.html)

Answer (score 1):

I guess u have one big E drive. Such big drive is not needed. Shrink that big partition and make some space for Ubuntu, may be 20~30GB is very adequate.

I think u know this already. Here's how u shrink your drive.

1. Go to Control Panel, change the View By to Large Icons
2. Click on Administrative Tools and double click on Computer Management.
3. Select Disk Management which is under Storage.
4. Right click on the partition and select SHRINK VOLUME
5. Make about 20~30GB of space for Ubuntu.
6. Delete this partition i.e. Ur marking it as free space

[image: Shrinking a Partition]

Once U have 30GB u can go ahead with Ubuntu installation in this way.

During Installation Select Specify Partitions Manually. *To begin creating partitions, select the free space and click on the Add… button.*
[image: Manual Partitioning]

- Click on the “Add” button. In the new window, type 2048 in the “New partition size in megabytes” field and select the “swap area” option from the “Use as:” list. Click the OK button.[image]
- Now, click on the “Add” button. In the new window, select the “Primary” option, input a value between 8,000 and 20,000 in the “New partition size in megabytes” field and select / as the “Mount point.” Click the OK button.[image]
- Click on the “Add” button again and from the new window and select the “Primary” option, type in whatever space you have left in your hard disk in the “New partition size in megabytes” field. And select /home as the “Mount point.” Click the OK button. You are done with the hard part.

Click “Install Now” to proceed with the installation process.

P.S.

There's also another wonderful Propitiatory Software for windows with which u can literally control Ur NTFS/FAT Partitions. Its called EASEUS Partition Master v5.5 Pro, U can use this to partition any Drive without loosing ur data.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of drive-letters is a windows thing. In fact you only need free space to install ubuntu. I guess 10 gb are enough to give it an ambitioned try, but more space can't hurt.

The Ubuntu installation fully supports an installation alongside with windows (you just have to click the option in the installer and adjust the partition sizes with a slider). As an alternative you can create another empty drive or free disc space with a windows partitioning software and install Ubuntu instead of the free disc space or the drive.

Both ways are not very complicated - and in the end it won't matter which way you choose.

When start the computer, the first thing you see is a selection menu (called grub) where you you can choose what OS to start.

Good luck installing Ubuntu.