# Why cant I find the programs I had on windows on ubuntu?

Tags: windows, files

I just installed ubuntu but I cant find the files that I had on windows?

Comment: well , you want see Windows installed programs in Ubuntu or data Files in Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by just installed - did you overwrite the windows partition with your install, install alongside windows, or are you using portable ubuntu from within windows...?

Comment: For people to help you, you need to clarify your question by adding details as to the Ubuntu installation process (dual boot or WUBI installed?), as well as what it is you need to access (files or programs) from Windows in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

#### Point 1:

Ubuntu and Windows are different Operating system. The softwares that work on One operation system may or may not work on another operating system (OS).

Generally, If two OS can run and recognize same [binary program/files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file), both of them can run that software. But, those files/programs need to be [binary compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code_compatibility). But, programs for Windows and Ubuntu's are not binari compatibles and hence they are different. So, You can't run your Windows programs on Ubuntu (except with the help of some emulation software such as WINE).

#### Point 2:

Even if You install another copy of Windows in another parititon in the same Computer, you will not find your installed programs (except the default programs automatically installed by Windows). Because, You have done installation in a new partition. Also, installing Windows again on the same drive will not help.

So, It is clear, If you install Ubuntu, you can't find the Windows programs in it. If you installed in another partition (other than Windows), You can still boot on Windows. If you installed Ubuntu on the same partition as Windows, You replaced Windows and you will never find those old Windows program.

---

See these links to get an idea about OSes, Difference between Windows and Ubuntu.

- [Operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)
- [Ubuntu - Operation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)
- [Windows - Operation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)

And also see these to get a general introduction to Ubuntu and Linux:

- [Ubuntu Linux Resources](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/)
- [Linux Newbie Guide](http://www.linuxnewbieguide.org/content/chapter-1-what-linux)

---

See these links to get help on Using both Windows and Ubuntu on the same computer:

- [How to dual boot with Windows 7 on an Ubuntu-only system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/158285/61218)
- [Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/q/65088/61218)