# About to dual boot Ubuntu with currently installed Windows 7 need expert advice!

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, nvidia, dual-boot, xps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65088/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-7)

So, I've tried this a dozen times with many a complications. I want advice on how to do this and avoid the pain.
The System:

Dell XPS L502x 
64 bit
8gb of RAM
currently running windows 7
Nvidia GeForce GT 525M <--- the culprit!!!!!

All I want to do is dual boot a nice Ubuntu OS and use both monitors.

So my question to all of you Ubuntu Gangstas out there:
Given my set up which version of Ubuntu should I use. What Kernals do I avoid installing and how  do I go about avoiding it.  I have found the 3.7 kernal isn't ready for the big time in this regard.  Is this true?  What can I do to get this to work. I'd like to run Ubuntu 12.10, but if it not a ready I'll avoid it.

Basically, if you had my exact system, and wanted to run a dual booting Windows 7/newest possible version of the might Ubuntu, how would you do it?

Comment: nope, this is specific to my system and about the graphic card I have. Not about the process of setting up Dual boot Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have L502, so all are from my personal experience.

- You can install any version of ubuntu (preferable >= 12.04) with any kernel.
- For Optimus setup, use bumblebee. Follow instruction here to [install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation)
- About dual moniter - Follow instruction [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup)

For your information, the **HDMI port is connected to nvidia chip**. So as per bumblebee wiki

> When the port is wired into the nvidia chip, you can currently not
>   expand the screen over monitors. The monitor may still be used as
>   extra screen (with no desktop running on it) or to run the full
>   desktop on it (with no output on the Intel LVDS output, a.k.a. "the
>   laptop display").

That means, **you can't use both display at same time.**

Comment: Can't use them at the same time?! NO Good! So, is it possible to use an adapter and connect via USB and DVI? Or is there just no current way to have a true dual monitor experience? Thanks for all the info, this looks promising!

Comment: I have never used multi monitor set up, so can't really help you there. :) [This link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html) was also mentioned i the wiki. Have a look.

Comment: I go the following advice when running `optirun true': `[ 4302.382263] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) [drm] Could not set DRM device bus ID.

[ 4302.382360] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 offers installation alongside an existing Windows installation, so make sure you choose this option. The grub bootloader will allow you to choose which OS to boot once installed.

Ubuntu 12.10 uses kernel 3.5. After installation enable proprietary 3rd party drivers and install `nvidia-current`, which has very good dual monitor support.

Comment: Some how I ended up with Kernel 3.7. I'll try a clean install and see how it goes.

Comment: installing `nvidia-current` to an optimus system will cause black screen/low resolution.

Comment: @Web-E I wasn't aware the GT 525M was an optimus card, thanks.

Comment: @Guided33 No Ubuntu distribution has 3.7 in the official repos afaik. 13.04 will have kernel 3.8.